# Multiple choics iPhone App - UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing a voting app, where the User will be presented with a question and multiple choices. In a typical HTML world the choice for this interface would be a Radio Box/Check box. What kind of view would I use in the iPhone SDK for a similar behavior?

Are there any sample apps which I can refer to?

Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're displaying repeating rows of data, UITableView is the natural choice.  UITableViewCell provides various properties for you to customize the `selected` state which you can use to show the user's selected choice.

Answer (score 0):

If your question has a few answer (3-4), then you can use an UIActionSheet. This is much quicker to code and provides a good looking user interface, with the sheet animating from then bottom of the iPhone and presenting to your user multiple button related to the possible choices/answers. It's a radio interface, in the iPhone Style.

Another possibility is to exploit an UISegmented control, a different type of radio interface.

If there are many answers, an UITableView is your best choice.